# Remove a document nested in an array via mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to remove a document that is nested inside of an array which is nested inside of a document in MongoDB.

Schema

```
{
  "_id": 12345,
  "id": 12345,
  "name": "Test",
  "links": [],
  "training": [],
  "about": [
    {
      "contents": "Test Contents 0",
      "heading": "Test Heading 0"
    },
    {
      "contents": "Test Contents 1",
      "heading": "Test Heading 1"
    },
    {
      "contents": "Test Contents 2",
      "heading": "Test Heading 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to remove the sub doc that matches the route

```
'/:_id/:section/:item'
```

Such that if I send a `DELETE` to `/12345/about/1`, the sub doc containing "Test Heading 1" will be removed entirely.

I've tried many different methods such as

```
.delete(function (req, res) {
    var section = req.params.section_name;
    var item = req.params.item;

    Tool.findOne({'id': req.params._id}, function (err, tool) {
        tool.set(section[item], null);
        tool.save(function (err) {
            res.send(err);
        })
    });
});
```

But none seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work perfectly

```
.delete(function (req, res) {
    var section = req.params.section_name;
    //convert string to int
    var item = +req.params.item; //or use parseInt(req.params.item)

    Tool.findOne({'id': req.params._id}, function (err, tool) {
        tool[section].splice(item, 1);
        tool.save(function (err) {
            res.send(err);
        })
    });
});
```

It's converted to

```
tool[section].splice(item, 1);
tool.about.splice(1, 1); //remove 1 item from given index
```

About splice

```
array.splice(index, 1);
```

> The second parameter of splice is the number of elements to remove. Note that splice modifies the array in place and returns a new array containing the elements that have been removed.

Comment: Strange. It's not setting it to `undefined`. It's getting the correct document but it's not actually setting it

Answer (score 0):

```
Tool.findOneAndUpdate(
{
   "_id": req.params._id, "about.heading": "Test Heading 1" 
   // 1. query above will target the document by _id.
   // 2. search [about] and get index then store it at "$",
   // 3. "Test Heading 1" is located at about[1], store it at "$"
   // 4. imagine this line is executed => var $ = 1
}, 
{
   $unset: {"about.$": 1} 
}, 
{
   new:true //means return the updated document (new instead old)

}) 
.exec((err, tool)=>{
    if(err) console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear but my intention is to remove the entire sub-doc completely that matches `/id/section/item`. See: "Such that if I send a DELETE to /12345/about/1, the sub doc containing "Test Heading 1" will be removed entirely."

Basically, I'm removing an item (given an index) in an array (given the name of the array) within a document (given its _id or id)